# Two drop down lists for a mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create two dropdown lists form, for example the first one would have "Advice A" and "Advice B" and the second one would have "Advice 1" and "Advice 2"

For example, a visitor would choose "Advice A" from the first dropdown list and "Advice 2" from the second dropdown list.

After clicking on the submit button, he would be redirected to http://www.domain.com/advice-a/advice-2/

I already have this code:

```
var getURL = function(){
var option1 = document.getElementById('dropDown1').value;
var option2 = document.getElementById('dropDown2').value;
var URL = 'http://www.domain.com/' + option1 + '/' + option2;
location.href=(URL); }

<select id="dropDown1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="dropDown2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>  
<button onclick="getURL()">Run</button>
```

1. I would like to make it compatible with all mobiles and tablets browsers. I heard i need it written in Jquery. What would be the code?
2. I would like a complete custom url http://www.domain2.com/custom-value/ if value "2" from dropDown1 and value "2" from dropDown2 is selected.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for jquery and try it yourself. Its really simple to understnad. Here is documenation: http://api.jquery.com
2. This would be some options:

   - http://www.domain.com/value1/value2
   - http://www.domain.com?value1=[]&value2=[]
   - http://www.domain.com/value1value2 (If you have 20 options on both drop downs, add a zero to the numbers smaller than 10)
   - My personal favourite would be the seccond.